# Как объединить вложенные словари с обычным в python

Tags: python, dict

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
У меня есть 2 словаря, и во втором у меня есть вложенный словарь:

```
"meaning": {
        "joy": 20,
        "satiety": 7,
        "fatigue": "Awake"
    }
```

Как я могу объединить вложенный словарь с обычным?

Во вложенном словаре может быть разное количество данных

Comment: Какие у вас проблемы при стандартом объединении словарей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно пробежаться по всем элементам вложенного словаря и записать их в другой, можно сделать, например, так:

```
old_dict = {
    "meaning": {
        "joy": 20,
        "satiety": 7,
        "fatigue": "Awake"
    }
}

new_dict = {}
for key, value in old_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for k, v in value.items():
            new_dict[k] = v

print(new_dict)
```